# List iterator not dereferencable run time

Tags: c++, visual-c++, iterator, artificial-intelligence, listiterator

I am getting this error on runtime Expression: List iterator not dereferencable.  below is the code I am using.

header file

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//  Name:   Fletcher_TargetingSystem.h
//
//  Author: Alan Fletcher (20040797)
//
//  Desc:   class to select a target from the opponents currently in a bot's
//          perceptive memory.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include "2d/Vector2D.h"
#include <list>
#include "../../AbstTargetingSystem.h"


class AbstRaven_Bot;

class Fletcher_TargetingSystem : public AbstTargetingSystem
{

public:
    Fletcher_TargetingSystem(AbstRaven_Bot* owner);

    //each time this method is called the opponents in the owner's sensory 
    //memory are examined and the closest  is assigned to m_pCurrentTarget.
    //if there are no opponents that have had their memory records updated
    //within the memory span of the owner then the current target is set
    //to null

    void       Update();
    void         closestBotStrategy();

    void      setCurrentTarget(AbstRaven_Bot* t);
    AbstRaven_Bot* getCurrentTarget();

    void      setCurrentOwner(AbstRaven_Bot* t);
    AbstRaven_Bot* getCurrentOwner();
};

class Fletcher_getClosestBotStrategy
{

public:
    Fletcher_getClosestBotStrategy()
    {}
    Fletcher_getClosestBotStrategy(AbstRaven_Bot* owner);

    //each time this method is called the opponents in the owner's sensory 
    //memory are examined and the closest  is assigned to m_pCurrentTarget.
    //if there are no opponents that have had their memory records updated
    //within the memory span of the owner then the current target is set
    //to null
    void      pickTarget(AbstRaven_Bot& owner);
};

#endif
```

c++ file

```
#include "Fletcher_TargetingSystem.h"
#include "../../AbstRaven_Bot.h"
#include "../../Raven_SensoryMemory.h"
#include "../../Debug/DebugConsole.h"


//-------------------------------- ctor ---------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Fletcher_TargetingSystem::Fletcher_TargetingSystem(AbstRaven_Bot* owner):
AbstTargetingSystem(owner){

}

//-------------------------------- ctor ---------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Fletcher_getClosestBotStrategy::Fletcher_getClosestBotStrategy(AbstRaven_Bot* owner){

}
std::list<AbstRaven_Bot*> SensedBots;
std::list<AbstRaven_Bot*>::const_iterator curBot;
//----------------------------- Update ----------------------------------------

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//----------------------------- closestPlayer ----------------------------------------

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Fletcher_getClosestBotStrategy::pickTarget(AbstRaven_Bot& owner)
{

    double ClosestDistSoFar = MaxDouble;

    Fletcher_TargetingSystem *fTS = new Fletcher_TargetingSystem(&owner);


    for (curBot; curBot != SensedBots.end(); ++curBot)
    {
        //make sure the bot is alive and that it is not the owner
        if ((*curBot)->isAlive() && (*curBot != fTS->getCurrentOwner()) )
        {
            double dist = Vec2DDistanceSq((*curBot)->Pos(), fTS->getCurrentOwner()->Pos());
            if (dist < ClosestDistSoFar)
            {
                ClosestDistSoFar = dist;
                fTS->setCurrentTarget(*curBot);// = *curBot;
            }

        }
    }
    //return *fTS;
}

void Fletcher_TargetingSystem::Update()
{
    // currentStrategy = targetClosestBotStrategy;
    // target = currentStrategy.pickTarget();
    //std::list<AbstRaven_Bot*> SensedBots;
    SensedBots = getCurrentOwner()->GetSensoryMem()->GetListOfRecentlySensedOpponents();
    curBot = SensedBots.begin();
    //std::list<AbstRaven_Bot*>::const_iterator curBot = SensedBots.begin();
    setCurrentTarget(0);//       = 0;

    Fletcher_getClosestBotStrategy* fGCBS = new Fletcher_getClosestBotStrategy(this->getCurrentOwner());
    fGCBS->pickTarget(**curBot);
}

AbstRaven_Bot* Fletcher_TargetingSystem::getCurrentOwner(){
    return m_pOwner;
}
AbstRaven_Bot* Fletcher_TargetingSystem::getCurrentTarget(){
    return m_pCurrentTarget;
}

void Fletcher_TargetingSystem::setCurrentTarget(AbstRaven_Bot* t){
    m_pCurrentTarget = t;
}
void Fletcher_TargetingSystem::setCurrentOwner(AbstRaven_Bot* t){
    m_pOwner = m_pOwner;
}
```

any help in telling me how to fix this would be appreciated
Thanking You

Also what does the error mean exactly and how/when does it occur

Comment: Is there ever a time where `GetListOfRecentlySensedOpponents()` would return an empty list?  And is `Update()` ever called during one of those times?

Answer (score 0):

You're initialising `curBot` here:

```
void Fletcher_TargetingSystem::Update()
{
    // ...
    curBot = SensedBots.begin();
    // ...
}
```

But you don't appear to call `Update()` anywhere, so on this line:

```
for (curBot; curBot != SensedBots.end(); ++curBot)
{ // ... }
```

You're attempting to use an uninitialised iterator, which is not dereferencable, as the error message indicates.

The solution: initialise `curBot` before you use it.

Side note: why is `curBot` declared at global scope? It would make more sense to declare/initialise it where you actually use it i.e. at the `for` loop.

Comment: Without seeing the main function, how can you determine that he never calls `Update()`?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley That's why I said "You don't *appear*" - it's an assumption based on an incomplete code sample. It's the OP's responsibility to supply a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), not mine to second guess whether he has or not.

Comment: there is about 60 or 70 classes and there is an update function Expression List iterators incompatible i get this error now

Comment: @AlanFletcher Could you rephrase that? I'm not sure what you mean. If you've solved the first problem and now have a different error message, please post a separate question for the new issue. Also, copy+pasting the exact error message in it's entirety is usually more helpful rather than trying to summarise it in your own words.

Comment: for (curBot; curBot != SensedBots.end(); ++curBot)
when I use this it gives this error Expression List iterators incompatible i dont think its fixed

Comment: @JBentley u said something about SSCCE, there was just way to much to paste it all i can attach the files if it makes it easier to see the problem

Comment: @AlanFletcher No, that's not necessary. SSCCE means you condense the code down to just enough to demonstrate the actual problem, without all the superfluous stuff. What Benjamin is saying is that you've given us the class, but you haven't given the code which *uses* the class, and the error might be in the way you're using it.

Comment: @AlanFletcher No, like I said, please post a second question for the second error, with a relevant code sample. You haven't given enough information to answer in it's current form because you're saying there's now a different error, but we don't know what code you've changed which results in that error.

Answer (score 0):

You nitialize the global:

```
std::list<AbstRaven_Bot*>::const_iterator curBot;
```

only inside Update() with:

```
SensedBots = getCurrentOwner()->GetSensoryMem()
              ->GetListOfRecentlySensedOpponents();
curBot = SensedBots.begin();
```

It is posible that you change `SensedBots` in other place (for example to other `getCurrentOwner()->GetSensoryMem()->GetListOfRecentlySensedOpponents();)` and dont set `curBot`, invalidating the previus value.

Typically you do:

```
for (curBot=SensedBots.begin();  curBot != SensedBots.end(); ++curBot)
```

Even if you call `Update()` making `curBot=SensedBots.begin();`  it is possible that you call `pickTarget()` 2 time, and `SensedBots` changed in size in betwen, invalidating the endlich first-call-value of  `curBot= SensedBots.end();` entering  the second time into the for cycle with a "falch" value.

Comment: but i did initialize it curBot = SensedBots.begin(); here

Comment: And you allways initialize it immediatly before the call of pickTarget ??

Comment: IF you change SensedBots you very posible invalidate curBot if not reinizialize it.

Comment: how would i reninitialize it

Comment: Why not just: for (curBot=SensedBots.begin();  curBot != SensedBots.end(); ++curBot)  ?